# Class "Class Magento\Captcha\Model\Zend" does not exist in magento 2.3.p5

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am working magento 2.3.p5 disable all captcha module Magento_Captcha,Magento_PaypalCaptcha, MSP_ReCaptcha and Magento_PaypalReCaptcha. Set these modules value in config.php file 0 and clear the cache. The website is working fine but when i am trying to load checkout or cart page giving error "**Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Captcha\Model\Zend does not exist**".

Can any guys help me on this how to sort-out this issues?

**Update**

The Error Screen i got on cart/checkout page as below:
[image]

On comment of @Divyarajsinh
I am unable to find the "1) admin/captcha/type and 2) customer/captcha/type" in core_config_data. Please check my table details in image below
[image]

**ANSWER**

I tried all answer that is related to my queries but still get the error. Finally i enable all the captcha module from command prompt and run command  php bin/magento setup:di:compile and clear the cache. The problem is solved.

Comment: Please search those paths: 1) admin/captcha/type and 2) customer/captcha/type in  core_config_data  table and delete the value of zend and run reindex command.

Comment: Please check question again i added update thier, may be that is help to you.

Comment: Delete entry of customer/captcha/type in table core_config_data. and check.

Comment: Didn't get  customer/captcha/type in table core_config_data? How can i find it?

Comment: @RaghwendraOjha have you found the solution?

Comment: Yes please, in my case i enable again the plugin, and disable from command prompt and it works. and after that run upgrade, compile, cache clean command and it works.